# How to execute a query just before insert in MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I need to execute a query before every insert into the table. I try to use instead of

```sql
--insert into tbl_Exlog(ActionName) values('Insert')
--select * from tbl_Exlog

ALTER Trigger [dbo].[trgExLogTest] on [dbo].[tbl_ExLog] 
Instead of Insert
as

begin
    insert into tbl_ExLog (ActionName) values('trigger')
end


 but it restricts the actual insert which I don't want.
```

Output :
ActionName
trigger

Insert is missing

Comment: *"it restricts the actual insert"* What do you mean by this?

Comment: I mean I need to execute both queries.  1. Before Insert 2. For Insert

Comment: Yeah... Why does an `INSTEAD OF` `TRIGGER` stop you doing that? It doesn't.

Comment: Posting your *actual* attempt might tell us what you have done wrong here.

Comment: My trigger query is executing as expected. But Insert query is not executing

Comment: *"My trigger query is executing as expected. But Insert query is not executing"* These statements conflict. if the trigger is executing, the `INSERT` is happening. One ***cannot*** happen without the other.

Comment: *"Insert is missing"* Because you didn't define it. You don't tell SQL Server to `INSERT` the data in your `TRIGGER` so it doesn't. An `INSTEAD OF INSERT` does **exactly** "what it says on the tin"; 'do *this* **instead of** the `INSERT'.

Comment: But trigger does not supports input parameter how i can pass inputs for insert

Comment: With the `inserted` pseudo table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INSERT` is missing, yes, in your `TRIGGER`. You never told SQL Server to `INSERT` the data, so it doesn't `INSERT` it. An `INSTEAD OF INSERT` "does **exactly** what it says on the tin"; 'do *this* **instead of** the `INSERT`'. You tell SQL Server to `INSERT` a row into `tbl_ExLog` *instead* but don't tell it to `INSERT` into the table you were actually inserting again.

Define the `INSERT` in your trigger:

```sql
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgExLogTest] ON [dbo].[tbl_ExLog] 
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_ExLog (ActionName) VALUES ('trigger');

    INSERT INTO dbo.trgExLogTest ({Column List})
    SELECT {Column List}
    FROM inserted;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks All done, only the issue is input parameters which i have for insert from c# side